# Retag [mpich2] as [mpich]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

The [mpich2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpich2) tag needs to be retagged as [mpich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpich). I thought I'd be able to do this as a synonym when I reached 2500 rep, but apparently, there are rules about "version" tags that prevent anyone but moderators from taking care of this.

[MPICH](http://www.mpich.org/) has been around for a while. It was originally called MPICH. For a brief period of time during its 2.0 days, it was called MPICH2. Then when it went to 3.0, the developers realized that was a stupid way of naming things and went back to just MPICH. As such, there's lots of confusion on the web about people referring to the project by both MPICH and MPICH2, when they really mean the same thing.

On SO, there seem to be some tags that usefully differentiate between different versions (all of the python tags for example), however this isn't one of them. There's no useful reason to differentiate between the two other than to mess with someone's brain. Can a diamond take care of this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All questions with the tag [mpich2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpich2) are either retagged to the tag [mpich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpich) or had their tag removed by me. I did improve one or two questions and voted to close one (as it appeared to be an issue caused by a typo).

When the magic 03:00 UTC script runs the tag mpich2 will be gone (unless a new question is tagged with it again)

Comment: "unless a new question is tagged with it again". Does this mean it's not a synonym?

Comment: No, based on your question I assumed the tag was no more valid so it better be gone. You could update the mpich wiki to reflect that the tag is used for all versions?

Comment: Of course. I was just confused by the last bit there and was afraid the tag would come back the next time someone tries to use it.

Comment: I keep an eye on it the next couple of days and if I see it reappear I will retag again. 2K rep users can always create a tag so that might occur...

Comment: Way to do all the work requested without having any sort of debate about it. Good to know that "community" has a distinct meaning to you (that appears disparate from what it *really* means).

Comment: The tag got now synomized as well, so it still is around.

Comment: @KyleKanos Wait, what? We had six people *agree* with this, no people *disagreed*, and *no one brought up any problems with this*. I'd say that's a community consensus.

Comment: @KyleKanos If you feel that the tag has its value you can still apply it...

Comment: @hichris123: I'd agree if, for instance, you had 15 up-votes. 6 votes to me says that no one really cared to even read the post (given the popularity of MSO as compared to individual sites' metas). You also implicitly assume that *everyone* who *has* an opinion actually checks MSO, a patently false position.

Comment: @KyleKanos If you have a particularly strong reason why the retagging/cleanup should not have happened (and perhaps why it should be reversed) then please make that an answer. If not .... this is all a bit of a moot point. Just move on.

Comment: @rene: I don't check MSO for anything b/c I don't care enough. What I do care about is getting RSS alerts to posts that are 4 years old because someone made a seemingly pointless modification to it without justifying it. You had a reason for modifying it, why not write a comment about the modification? I would've left well enough alone to that

Comment: @KyleKanos OK, I'll take that step the next time. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: @KyleKanos if you have an opinion but don't check Meta, you'll have to live with other people making the decisions. You're being extremely  rude to someone who did nothing wrong. At the moment the question has 48 views and 8 upvotes, that is a *spectacularly* good ratio. What should people do, ask the owner of every question in advance whether a retag would offend their sensibilities?